# .htaccess url changes when accessing from non www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server, xampp

I have this on my .htaccess

```
Options -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

from my knowledge this will pass all the arguments to $_GET['url'] and force my url to www.
but when i access the url to

```
http://www.example.net/user/login
```

it works perfectly but when i remove the "www." the url become like this

```
http://www.example.net/index.php?url=user/login
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Rewrite|Redirect non-www to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Rewrite|Redirect www to non-www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: thankyou for answering, I've tried your example and it fix the problem but now it doesn't pass any argument to $_GET variable anymore.

Comment: fix the problem by revising your code a little bit thankyou again.

Comment: @MashiruAlexis - Do you want to append the url=user Query String to all URI's or just the index.php page/script or just the /login URI?  From what you have posted in your question I think you want to end up with this URI and Query String: `http://www.example.net/user/login?url=user` for just the /login URI. Is that correct?  If not, then post the URI and Query String that you want as the final result.